# Parsing a URL param changes the value in Python

Tags: python-3.x, url-parameters, url-parsing

I´m trying to get a param from a URL using the urlparse function, but when i tried to decode the param the string changes and gives me an error. like this:

```
    url = request.url
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    log.info(parsed)
    url_code = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['id_compra']
    log.info(url_code)
```

the output looks like this

```
INFO     http://c34f30683db9.ngrok.io/payment?id_compra=%2FYkv86B1UdMds9CuYr%2FbMCD3BpKL%2FzElNtVRc8KiALXWgtB343EjrUsmTObrBzv48FshzRu%2FD3Www4B+5SAxcb2xx78=
INFO     ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='c34f30683db9.ngrok.io', path='/payment', params='', query='id_compra=%2FYkv86B1UdMds9CuYr%2FbMCD3BpKL%2FzElNtVRc8KiALXWgtB343EjrUsmTObrBzv48FshzRu%2FD3Www4B+5SAxcb2xx78=', fragment='')
INFO     ['/Ykv86B1UdMds9CuYr/bMCD3BpKL/zElNtVRc8KiALXWgtB343EjrUsmTObrBzv48FshzRu/D3Www4B 5SAxcb2xx78=']
```

I want to obtain the param like it is in the URL, but the result changes the character '+' to an empty space and I don't want that to happen.

Comment: `unquote_plus(parsed.query)`

Comment: Unquote_plus is the opposite of what i want, i want to keep the plus in the string. I need the string as it is so i can decrypt it

Comment: then use `unquote(parsed.query)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably quote the query to get back to the urlsafe format.  urlparse some some simple unquoting of the query and you just need to reverese that process.

```
from urllib.parse import quote
urlsafequery = quote(urlquery)
```